# Qt5 QProcess handling arguments with "special" characters

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ftp

I'm maintaining a `Qt5` program that uses `QProcess` to execute `ncftpget` on `Linux`.

The command that I'm attempting to execute is:

`ncftpget -E -Z -u username -p 'a#$b1379' 1.1.1.1 /x/y/temp/ update/file`

Which simply transfers a file from a server into a local directory. If I execute the above command on the bash command line it works properly.

However, when my `Qt5` application executes the same command using `QProcess` the `ftp` server replies saying the username/password is not correct. When the password doesn't contain any "special" characters it works properly.

As mentioned by [S.M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6752050/s-m) `QProcess` isn't executing the command in a shell. So I'm assuming `fork()` and some version of the `exec()` call is made. **How do I make `QProcess` do the correct thing here?**

I'm assuming that the problem has do to with the special character(s) in the password. When I build my `QProcess` argument list I specifically make sure the password is surrounded by `'` so that the special characters are escaped.

Code snippet:

```
processFTP.setParent(this->parent());
processFTP.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);

// ncftpArgs is a QStringList
// snippet doesn't show complete argument list

ncftpArgs->push_back("-Z");
ncftpArgs->push_back("-u");//username
ncftpArgs->push_back(QString((*phashSettings)[FTPUSERNAME]));
ncftpArgs->push_back("-p");//pw
// password can have special characters when shell executes command.
QString password((*phashSettings)[FTPPASSWORD]);
password.prepend("'");
password.append("'");
ncftpArgs->push_back(password);

ncftpArgs->push_back(QString((*phashSettings)[FTPSERVERIP]));
ncftpArgs->push_back(QString((*phashSettings)[FTPTEMPDIR]));

//beging the ncftpget session
QString sExe = "ncftpget";  //process name

// processFTP is a QProcess object
processFTP.start(sExe, (*ncftpArgs));
bSuccess = processFTP.waitForStarted();

// .... more code to monitor process etc...
```

The code logs the command and arguments that will passed to `processFTP` and everything looks correct.

**How do I properly set up the arguments and start the `QProcess` object so that the password argument containing the special characters are properly passed to the executable `ncftpget`?**

**And/or how do I go about debugging the problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I build my QProcess argument list I specifically make sure the password is surrounded by ' so that the special characters are escaped.

Do not append or prepend the password with `'`, remove these lines

```
password.prepend("'");
password.append("'");
```

`QProcess::start` is responsible for proper way of program arguments passing. Besides bash interpreter is not run by this call in your code.

Comment: If I leave the password argument as is it doesn't work though. I get the same result - unable to login to the ftp server because the password is wrong. If the bash shell isn't called, then I assume QProcess does some sort of exec() call?

Comment: Yes, it does fork() and execve().

Comment: Thank you S.M. So what can I do to get `execve()` to pass the arguments with "special characters" to the executable?

Comment: Special characters are not interpreted, pass them as they are. If your Qt is built with `QPROCESS_DEBUG` then try enable debug logs.

Comment: Why do you not use QFtp Class?

Comment: Special characters are not interpreted? They seem to be in my case though. Weird. If I specify a password without special characters everything works properly.

Comment: As to why I'm not using `QFtp`, it's a legacy application completely written around using `ncftp` commands. I don't have the luxury of rewriting it.

Comment: You did not post [mcve], I do not mind what is `(*phashSettings)[FTPPASSWORD])`. I am not able to help you more.